# Avoiding intermediate computation in folding a spark column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fold

I'm looking to create a function that takes some sequence of numbers and a spark column, then **efficiently** computes a new column with the highest number matched from the list, defaulting to 0 if none are matched.

For example take the sequence [500, 100, 1].

The naive approach is to do manually write the following for the sequence:

```
val manualAdjustment = (c: Column) => 
    when(c.isNull, -1)
      .when(c > 500, 500)
      .when(c > 100, 100)
      .when(c > 1, 1)
      .otherwise(0)
```

When we supply a column, for example `lit(1)` we get the concise and clean plan:

```
CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (1 > 500) THEN 500 WHEN (1 > 100) THEN 100 WHEN (1 > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END.
```

It would be much nicer to have a function that composes this same plan given a column and an arbitrary sequence of ordered integers instead of manually writing out the prior code for each sequence.

This lead me to write the following function:

```
val makeRange: (Column, Seq[Int]) => Column = (col: Column, range: Seq[Int]) => {
  val whenFunction = (c: Column, condition: Column, value: Int) => 
       c.when(condition, value)
  val reduced: Column => Column = 
       range.map(i => (column: Column) => whenFunction(column, column > i, i))
            .reduce(_ compose _)
  reduced(when(col.isNull, -1)).otherwise(0)
}
```

This function maps each int to a when condition based on the column value being larger than than the int, so at least in theory it does the same operations as the `manualAdjustment` function above. However, the output of `makeRange(lit(1), Seq(500, 100, 1))` is instead:

```
CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 END > 500) THEN 500 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 END > 500) THEN 500 END > 100) THEN 100 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 END > 500) THEN 500 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (CASE WHEN (1 IS NULL) THEN -1 END > 500) THEN 500 END > 100) THEN 100 END > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This plan is at the least much more verbose than the other plan, but seems much less efficient as it (seemingly) has to calculate the same where conditions over and over again. My theory is that the when conditions are computed in place and applying further when conditions requires evaluating the former 'step' in the fold, which makes requires computing the same conditions over and over again.

Any insight into why this is happening, or how to write a function similar to `makeRange` that creates as simple of a plan as `manualAdjustment`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to create the same plan as your `manualAdjustment`:

```
val makeRange = (c: Column, range:Seq[Int]) =>
  range.foldLeft(when(c.isNull, -1))((acc: Column, curr: Int) => acc.when(c>curr,curr)).otherwise(0)

== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [CASE WHEN (i IS NULL) THEN -1 WHEN (i > 500) THEN 500 WHEN (i > 100) THEN 100 WHEN (i > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END#10]
```